# How to get trust limit of asset?

Tags: assets

I have an issuer account I1 and a distributor account D1. I have added trust of an asset `DummyAsset` issued by I1 with trust limit of `5000 DummyAsset`.

How can I later verify/check the trust limit of a particular asset programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Horizon [`/account/{account}`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/accounts-single.html) endpoint returns current balances, including trust limit for each asset in the list.

Each balance record looks like the following:

```
{
  "balance": "126.8107491",
  "limit": "5000.0000000",
  "asset_type": "credit_alphanum4",
  "asset_code": "BAR",
  "asset_issuer": "GBAUUA74H4XOQYRSOW2RZUA4QL5PB37U3JS5NE3RTB2ELJVMIF5RLMAG"
}
```

In order to retrieve the limit for the specified balance you need to load an account and enumerate through balance entries to find your asset. Check this sample code (JS):

```
server.accounts()
  .accountId('GCEZWKCA5VLDNRLN3RPRJMRZOX3Z6G5CHCGSNFHEYVXM3XOJMDS674JZ')
  .call()
  .then(account => account.balances.filter(balanceRecord => balanceRecord.asset_code === 'BAR' && 
    balanceRecord.asset_issuer === 'GBAUUA74H4XOQYRSOW2RZUA4QL5PB37U3JS5NE3RTB2ELJVMIF5RLMAG')[0])
  .then(balanceRecord => {
    if (!balanceRecord) return Promise.reject('Trustline does not exist.')
    Promise.resolve(balanceRecord.limit)
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```