# How do I see trustline subentries in an account?

Tags: accounts, trustline

Are trustline sub entries about trustline created to asset issued by my account or the trustline I have created to other assets of different accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking about the `account <-> trustline` relation. A trustline is related directly to the account that establishes the trustline, not the asset issuer account. That's why an issuing account details does not contain any balance records for the issued assets (for example, see [Mobius issuing account](https://horizon.stellar.org/accounts/GA6HCMBLTZS5VYYBCATRBRZ3BZJMAFUDKYYF6AH6MVCMGWMRDNSWJPIH) details).

To see the truslines established by the account, all you need is to load the account using Horizon [`/account/{account}`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/horizon/reference/endpoints/accounts-single.html) endpoint and enumerate through account balances. I've already answered a similar question today, check it [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/834/how-to-get-trust-limit-of-asset).